# APK 50meg+ Expansion Packs and Flash

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, apk, expansion

So Google Play has come out with their new Expansion Pack setup, allowing apps to shoot past the 50meg limit.

I've set up a 42 meg APK file, and tested it manually by placing my main expansion file in shared storage as outlined in this massive document: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

Everything tests fine, but the problem I'm having is that Google Play won't download the expansion file automatically when you download the application. Meaning I have to run a check inside my application, and download it in there.

Now that's all well and good, but I'm working in AS3 + Air, and my native extension code that deals with the license checking needs to be altered to allow the extra expansion pack URL field to come through, but I'm at my wit's end.

Long story short, has anyone had any luck with downloading expansion files in an AS3 application compiled in AIR?

If not, I'll keep slogging away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given my deadline I opted to host my own files in an Amazon bucket and download them in a more traditional way.

Saved the data to the Android Shared Storage.

Everything turned out better than expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. But I just downloaded the expansion file (.obb) and find the using the File Class. You can go to File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("Android/data/obb/name_of_your_app") and after get the .obb inside this folder.

You can use the FZIP Class to extract the file and open in your app. I did this and work well.