# Create expansion file for AS3 android Air App Flash cs6

Tags: android, flash-cs6, mobile-application, apk-expansion-files

I have created an AS3 mobile app and exported successfully through flash CS6.

In this .apk I have included my video files (going to be a presentation for Android Tablet). The total size of the .flvs alone is 64mb.

When I tried to upload to Google play I got the (expected) warning about the file size being **>50mb**.

I have spend two hours trying to find a fix, including using the **jobb.bat** , **zipalign.bat** , putting the files into the format of **main.1.obb** and many other options.

The Google website seems to think that I am using Eclipse (which I’m not I used Flash CS6), but I tried all those tools anyway, but yielded zero results.

I have tried 
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html -

**But** seems extremely complex and assumes I have eclipse. I even tried to import the “android-sdk\extras\google\play_apk_expansion” into Flash builder, but is not the right project extension.

I looked all over Stack Overflow to articles such as :

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385776/how-to-attach-a-expansion-file-to-an-as3-air-application/15232051#15232051][2]

**– But** no response as of yet

[AS3 / AIR Google Play application id and expansion files access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782703/as3-air-google-play-application-id-and-expansion-files-access)

**- But** no clear answer, and I don’t even know how this got the .obb file in the first place.

[APK 50meg+ Expansion Packs and Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781410/apk-50meg-expansion-packs-and-flash)

**-But** I don’t have a Amazon bucket account. Also not sure what android shared storage is.

[Steps to create APK expansion file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file/11717019#11717019)

**– But** is using older version of google ( I don’t have the “Add Extra Button” ) Also this is not from a Flash As3 project , and again relies on Eclipse.

[APK 50meg+ Expansion Packs and Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781410/apk-50meg-expansion-packs-and-flash)

**-But** this person already has the .obb file (HOW ?).

As you can see I have tried many different ways, but I can’t simple create the expansion way.

So in Short ;

```
    Dose anyone one have a clear cut step by step technique on how to upload an .apk
    created in Flash CS6 that is >50MB to Google Play ?
```

Comment: same problem here. no answer yet?

Comment: Sorry, Saariko , I didn't get it going. I was lucky to distribute  it myself , we simply put the .apk file on our own site, as it was for a client, rather than the community in general.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to prepare obb - no need to use jobb.

The easiest way to use expansion file for air app is to make one small swf as preloader and use it as a main apk and the other swf file (that will be loaded) with all big data is stored in obb file.

so:
preloader.swf -> apk
app.swf -> obb

In this scenario you don't have to make an obb file, you just upload new apk to google play and after uploading apk in expansion file section change 'no expansion file' to 'upload a new file' and select your app.swf file. Google will change swf to obb you don't need to do it.

When you upload your first apk for a new app you won't be able to add an obb file. You have to upload just apk and then add new version of apk - this enables obb option.

Now you have to load app.swf from apk in your preloader class. I'm using something like that:

```
private var mainVersion:String="1000001";
private var path:String = "Android/obb/com.your.app.id";
private var filename:String= "main." + mainVersion + ".com.your.app.id.obb";//patch for second obb
private var file:File;
private var fileStream:FileStream;
private var bytes:ByteArray;
private var applicationLoader:Loader;

public function App() 
{
    file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(path + "/" + filename);

    if (file.exists)
    {
        loadSwf();
    }
}

private function loadSwf():void 
{
    fileStream = new FileStream(); 
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    bytes = new ByteArray();
    fileStream.readBytes(bytes);
    fileStream.close(); 

    var cont:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    cont.allowCodeImport = true;

    applicationLoader = new Loader();
    applicationLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleAppLoaded);
    applicationLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, handleProgress);

    applicationLoader.loadBytes(bytes, cont);
}

private function handleProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void 
{
    trace(int(100 * e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal))
    //just add progress bar if you want
}

private function handleAppLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
    addChild(applicationLoader);
}
```

And you can add a splash screen in preloader ;)

If you have to update obb file you have to also recompile apk with new mainVersion

If you ant to use zip file instead of swf, you have to upload a zip file, and in preloader you have to process it - unpack and use data from unpacked folder.

Comment: Thanks for the code. this much works perfect. Now how do I read the contents inside the obb file. I have few .swf files inside the .obb which I want to load one at a time.

Comment: How can I test that this works? The file it is loading does not exists on my file system, right?

Comment: @Bhaijaan I was using just one swf, if you want to have more you probably want to zip them and upload zip file as an extension file, but then in your container file you have to treat obb as a zip so unzip it using favorite zip library for as3, copy swfs from zip into app known location and then load swf's from there. Downside is that first run will take longer because of unzipping

Comment: @SimenØianGjermundsen the only final test I found was making the whole process using google play, so uploading container apk adding extension file (swf that google changes to obb) and then after few hours downloading the app from google play. During development I don't use container apk, I simply publish main app as apk container is being used only in final step when publishing to google play. But that's just my way

Comment: @Misiek has there been any other way to get around this? or is unzipping still the only way? if its still the only way, which zipping library has better uncompressing speed?