# Flash AIR - File size is to big for google store? What to do?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

We are making an app that contains all the menus for about 70 restaurants. Each menu is a pretty big image, and the user grabs it and drags it around the screen. It is pretty awesome. However, the file size is about 115 mb. The google store maximum is 50mb. It is saying I should someone break it into two .apk files. But two 50 mb files won't really be enough...
Or should I somehow take the images from a server? I have used electroserver, but I am pretty bad with php, and I think that I what you would need for doing something like this. Links are welcomed.

Comment: Assuming the images consume 100MB (giving room for the AIR runtime, code, and toher assets), you are looking at 1.42MB per image. You can definitely lower that through compression or even lowering JPG quality. If you are on a Mac, I highly recommend ImageOptim. Beyond that, I really do have to recommend you host the images on a server and pull them in as needed rather than having them available in the apk. Easier to update menus this way and it would solve your issue

Answer (score 4):

Personally I find the thought of an app, whose sole purpose is to show restaurant menues, taking up 115MB of space on my phone a really bad idea.

One solution as proposed by Jave is to use [APK expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). An expansion file can be a maximum of 2GB and that is more than sufficient for your needs. The question is if Flash AIR apps support this (there's an unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232572/create-expansion-file-for-as3-android-air-app-flash-cs6)).

A better solution would be to host the menues on your own server. You could go with something as simple as a Dropbox folder and use the public link to that folder as your base URL. Moving the menues to a server has two benefits:

1) It should drastically reduce the size of your APK
2) It allows individual restaurants to change a menu without you having to rebuild and republish your entire app

The drawback would be that your users need a working network connection to open a menu (you could cache previously downloaded menus).

You could also as an extra step add functionality to download a new list of restaurants from the server (in XML, JSON or similar format). This would allow you to add or remove menus without having to rebuild the app.

Answer (score 1):

If there any way to decrease the file size, do that first. If the apk is still to big, use an [APK Expansion File](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html), they can contain up to 2GB.

> some apps need more space for high-fidelity graphics, media files, or
>   other large assets. Previously, if your app exceeded 50MB, you had to
>   host and download the additional resources yourself when the user
>   opens the app. Hosting and serving the extra files can be costly, and
>   the user experience is often less than ideal. To make this process
>   easier for you and more pleasant for users, Google Play allows you to
>   attach two large expansion files that supplement your APK.

Comment: Or you can, you know, find a way to make the images take up less space.

Comment: True, and preferable. But then again - flash. Edited the answer nontheless.