# Uploading Adobe Air APK 300MB

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, apk-expansion-files

I have made a game using Adobe Animate, and I'm trying to upload it to the Play Store. However the limit for uploading is 100MB and my project is 300 MB. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232572/create-expansion-file-for-as3-android-air-app-flash-cs6?fbclid=IwAR1f8GexOJ0Wbbcp8cXZxh0j0SOsMTBs38guzgQgaJChfP-_PuHP7T09DtM) guide to create an expansion. My issue is that I'm not exactly sure where to put the script, and I'm new to programming as well. I have tried adding the code from the guide to a frame, what am I doing wrong? Any help would be great.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you straight ahead, but your problem does have a simple solution (the guide link is pretty explanatory), but in order to implement this solution you need is **a lot** of understanding. What is APK, what is SWF application, how to split your project into pieces and how to load/unload/manage these pieces at runtime - at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use obb files with AIR would be using an ANE (Native Extension). This [Expansion Files ANE](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.ExpansionFiles) will allow you to easily manage downloading obb files and there is also a very good guide on how to do the whole process.